# Why does my model only pass on a single row instead of all rows?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm running a query inside my model which returns results based on other results from a previous query, the query works perfectly fine, however it only returns a single row instead of all rows like it should.

I've tried returning the `$rows[]` in an array but that doesn't work, the query doesn't generate any results based on the first query, as I said though, there has to be a way to create these arrays in the controller given I return `result_array();`.

> model

```
public function category_id_results($category) {

  return $this->db->
  select('*')->
  from('categories')->
  where('parent_id', $category)->
  get()->result_array();
}
public function category_results($category, $id) {

  print_r($id);
  $where = "category_id='$id' OR category_id='$category'";
  $this->db->where($where);
  $query = $this->db->get('records');

  $rows = array();
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {

    $rows[] = array(
     //Rows
    );
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

> controller

```
  $this->load->model('Main');
  $category = $_GET["category"];

  $data['id_cat'] = $this->Main->category_id_results($category);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data['id_cat']);
  echo "</pre>";
  $id = $data['id_cat']['id'];

  $data['category_results'] = $this->Main->category_results($category, $id);
```

When I run a `print_r($data['id_cat']);` I get the expected output(all rows), it does however tell me that the `id` index is undefined. Also when I do this my query doesn't work properly either.

Comment: most likely you'll get your id like this: $id = $data['id_cat'][0]['id'];

Comment: yea I changed the `select` in the `category_id_results` function to just select the id, now I have a multidimensional array which naturally the DB doesn't recognize, so that's an ` Array to string conversion` error. The first function results look like this: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 ))`

Comment: well:  $id = $data[0]['id'];

Comment: yea exactly, but why? How do I change that?

Comment: look at your output: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 ))`

Comment: also read this, it's important to understand arrays: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I've made some changes though, my `$data['id_cat']` is called something else and is no longer an array, I then did `$var->id;` to get the id and I now only have one error: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198612/discussion-between-frogman578-and-vickel).

Comment: It looks like getting the results you want could be done with a single query. Care to add the schema for both tables? Also, it would be good to know exactly what `$category` contains and if you expect `category_id_results($category)` to find more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it appears you are expecting a single row as a result from `category_id_results`

If this is the case, you can change the last line from

`get()->result_array();`

to

`get()->row_array();`

and then you can use `$data['id']` instead of `$data[0]['id']`.

When you return a `result_array` it will always be indexed with integers, even if there is only one row.

If you expect multiple rows, you can use a handy foreach loop to iterate the results even if you do not know exactly how many there are.

Starting from the last line of your code:

```
$data['category_results'];

foreach ($data['category_results'] as $result) {
    echo $result['id'];
}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked but still getting only one row, and I know for a fact that I have other matching rows too

Comment: On another note, I want all results, not a single

Comment: Oh I figured something out, I have to use integer between the `$data` and `['id']`, how do I supply an array of integers for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this if want all record instead of single row

```
 $where = "category_id='$id' OR category_id='$category'";
  $this->db->where($where);
  $query = $this->db->get('records')->result_array();
```